# What's wrong with this DRL file?

Tags: drools

When trying to parse the following file, I get the error

> [10,4]: [ERR 101] Line 10:4 no viable alternative at input 'condition3' in rule "01"[17,3]: [ERR 101] Line 17:3 no viable alternative at input 'condition1' in rule "02"[17,17]: [ERR 101] Line 17:17 no viable alternative at input 'condition2' in rule "02"

```
package test;

global MessageProcessingResult result;
global Boolean condition1;
global Boolean condition2;
global Boolean condition3;

rule "01"
    when
        ( condition3 == false);     
    then 
        result.addErrorCode("ERROR_CODE1");
end

rule "02"
    when
        (condition1 && condition2);
    then
        result.addErrorCode("ERROR_CODE2");
end
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **eval** should work:

```
when
  eval(condition3 == false)
then
  ...
```

But I 'd recommend to use facts instead of globals to insert those conditions.